# Changing size of selected UICollectionView Cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a simple UICollectionViewController that returns X amount of cells. I want to have it so when a cell is selected, that specific selected cell will change it's size and become larger in height as all of the other cells stay the same. How do I achieve this? Here's my code:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)

        collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = (view.frame.width) * 9 / 16
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height + 50 + 50)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check to see if the `indexPath` from `sizeForItemAt` is selected. If it is, you return a different height otherwise return the standard height.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
    case .some(indexPath):
        return CGSize() // your selected height
    default:
        let height = (view.frame.width) * 9 / 16
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height + 50 + 50)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: How can this be modified so if I tap on the same cell, it goes back to the previous size?

Comment: Tapping the same cell would be deselecting it – you can use the delegate method `didDeselectItemAt` to recognize this and similarly call `performBatchUpdates` in order to revert the cell back to the default size in the switch statement.

Comment: For some reason, this does not animate the change. It does change its height, but it doesn't animate the change, it just goes straight from one height to the other. Any idea why? I am using the exact same code

Comment: I've not seen switching on an `Optional` like that before; I like it.